# malformed query expected END_OBJECT

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am running the following GET query within my Kibana Console and for some reason I am getting a error in the response window as follows :

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "parsing_exception",
                "reason": "[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
                "line": 6,
                "col": 7
            }
        ],
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
        "line": 6,
        "col": 7
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

GET _search

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {              "match_phrase": {"message": "some text}}
      },
      "filter": {
    "range": {
"@timestamp":{ "time_zone": "+03:00", "lte": "now-1d/d", "gte": "now-1d/d" }
}
}
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Both** `must` and `filter` need to be wrapped inside the `bool` query:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "message": "some text"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "time_zone": "+03:00",
              "lte": "now-1d/d",
              "gte": "now-1d/d"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**By the way, it's good practice to use `must`, `filter`, `should`, and `must_not` as arrays.**

That way, new conditions and clauses can be easily needed. On top of that, you'll have a clearer query structure and it'll be harder to confuse the query components with one another.